# How can i create combine Gregorian and Islamic(Hijri) FSCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar, fscalendar

Can you please tell me. I changed calendar identifier like this 
but it shows a warning (Changing Calendar identifier is not recommended).

`_calendar.identifier = NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic;`

Comment: "Changing Calendar identifier is not recommended", wow, that's racist.

Comment: @Loxx Yes, do you know the solution for that?

Comment: lol, no, i don't, sorry man